# How do I detect a lost client connection in a server that inherits from pb.Root?

Tags: python, twisted

For example, I have a client that connects to the server with the following:

```
class MyClientFactory(pb.PBClientFactory, ReconnectingClientFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        pb.PBClientFactory.__init__(self)
        self.ipaddress = None

    def clientConnectionMade(self, broker):
        log.msg('Started to connect.')
        pb.PBClientFactory.clientConnectionMade(self, broker)

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        log.msg('Connected to %s' % addr)
        return pb.PBClientFactory.buildProtocol(self, addr)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        log.msg('Lost connection.  Reason:', reason)
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        log.msg('Connection failed. Reason:', reason)
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)
```

So the client can automatically detect when a connection is lost.

How do I get the same behaviour from the server should a client go down, for example crashing?

I currently catch a DeadReferenceError, (by iterating through a list of potentially connected clients) but that is a non-event driven way  - and frankly too late.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Ben

Answer (score 4):

You can register a callback to be invoked when the connection is lost.  There are two APIs for this, one is `Broker.notifyOnDisconnect`, the other is `RemoteReference.notifyOnDisconnect`.  They do the same thing, but one or the other might be more convenient to access depending on the details of your application.

I'm not sure if you can use this to **guarantee** that you'll never get `DeadReferenceError` (for example, I'm not sure what happens if a `remote_foo` method if yours is invoked, you return a Deferred, the connection is lost, and then the Deferred fires), but you can at least drastically reduce the possibility in the common case (ie, you should be able to always avoid getting `DeadReferenceError` from `callRemote` if you never use `callRemote` after `notifyOnDisconnect` calls back your function).